# jmeter vars.put with an object javascript

Tags: variables, object, jmeter

I'm trying to use `vars.put` to write the result of the property of an object in a jmeter variable in javascript, but i have an issue...

Here is my code:

```
eval('var obj = ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString());
var meta_key = vars.get("MetaKey"); //meta_key is a variable
```

This works fine:

```
vars.put("content_metakey", obj[meta_key]);
```

but when i do this, it's doesn't work:

```
vars.put("taille", obj.meta_key[0].id); //meta_key variable
vars.put("taille", obj.tag[0].id); //tag is the value
```

Do you have any clue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `obj.meta_key[0]` have an id?

Comment: yes every value of meta_key has an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if it's possible, so i used another way to do this: i used another eval.

my code:

> obj2 = eval(obj[meta_key]);
>   vars.put("id_metakey"+meta_type,obj2[0].id);

Comment: If it worked then accept your answer but if your response is JSON, this way is not the best one. Javascript is not efficient compared to other scripting languages